# Replacement doors are about an inch wide and cover part of heat return holes. Can i seal this with caulk and what would i use to brace?

Tags: fireplace

I bought a set to cover fireplace doors. Gave exact measurements and stated I had double blowers for heat return to house. What I received is slightly covering the return holes and the bracing can't be put on as the blower cover is further out from frame and angled.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. A) We can't see what you see, so pics would be handy. B) Sounds like this was a custom order job and that you didn't receive what was specified - ask for a do-over. While I applaud the DIY spirit, I don't understand the acceptance of shoddy work with a "I'll just fix someone else's sad excuse for quality". Take pics of your attempt to install to the company that made this and show them that it doesn't fit and that it doesn't meet the specified measurements. C) If it _does_ meet measurements, it's best to say so in your request so people don't get mislead.

Comment: If you custom-ordered a specific size and recieved a different size, you withhold payment until you are given the size you ordered.